# Changing UITableView height with animateWithDuration causing UITableViewCell weird

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

basically I make a view that nest on the bottom, on pressing the orange button, I make the view slide up (changing the height). The view contains a UITableView that anchored to the top and bottom of the view, to the UITableView also got resized in the process.

All behaves correctly except the UITableViewCell inside the UITableView is layouting weirdly. (screenshoot attached).
I suspect calling the `UIView animateWithDuration` make the UITableView generate new cell due to height change and the UITableViewCell adjusting it's layout on a duration that make it weird

Is there any way to prevent UITableViewCell behave like that?

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Where in your code are you animating? Note: your screenshots don't really explain your problem.

Comment: Animation is only done by toggling the priority of 1 autolayout constant. and then call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` inside a `[UIView animateWithDuration]`. The screenshoots is showing the problem. as you can see, the orange button is sliding up and UITableView is resizing. The main problem is UITableViewCell weird layout animation